# In a Xamarin Forms (Android), what's the purpose of "Activity(Label =" in MainActivity.cs?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code in my app:

```
namespace JTest.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Test+", Theme = "@style/MainTheme")]
    public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
```

Does anyone know what the purpose of the `Label = "Test+",` is and why the developer might have included this?

Comment: The label is the title of your activity, Also the name of your application if its the launcher activity and there is no app name explicitly given, to your app (at least that was how it was the last time I checked )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lable` attribute is Activity Title Bar.

By default, Android gives your application a title bar when it is run. The value used for this is [/manifest/application/activity/@android:label](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label). 
In most cases, this value will differ from your class name. To specify your app's label on the title bar, use the [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.activityattribute.label?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_App_ActivityAttribute_Label) property. For example:

```
[Activity (Label="Awesome Demo App")]
public class MyActivity : Activity
{

}
```

This example produces the following xml fragment:

```
 <activity android:label="Awesome Demo App" 
      android:name="md5a7a3c803e481ad8926683588c7e9031b.MainActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`Label` determine the activity title as shown in the Android launcher.